# HashMap Rehashing on the basis of Size

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I  am having one question that rehashing in `HashMap` always occurs when size reaches `loadFactor*capacity+1`. Now Suppose Initially there are 16 Buckets, and I am inserting Object which has a bad implementation of hashCode means returning same value i.e. 1. Now at this point even after insertion of 13 elements, rehashing will take places but if you see then all elements are in one bucket in form of LinkedList and other 15 buckets are empty.So why Rehashing done on the basis of Size and Not Capacity. In HashMap, there is a re-calculation of hashCode using out provided HashCode but that will also return the same value.

Comment: Probably because the authors of `HashMap` intended that its users implement a proper or reasonable hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

`HashMap` doesn't know that all 13 elements returned the same `hashCode()`.

They could have returned 13 different hash *codes*, that just happened to all map into the same hash *bucket*, and re-hashing may then map them all into different buckets.

Adding logic to detect a bad `hashCode()` implementation is not feasible.

Comment: Yes but in Java 8 they finally come up with an idea to convert to Tree instead of LinkedList if all keys are going in same bucket which will hit Threshold. You are write but my question is if ReHashing will be done on the basis of Capacity , then what is the issue, because if HasCode are different then  size will be equivalent to Capacity else Capacity will be more so no need of rehashing. Also rehashing will reuse our own hashcode and on the basis of that HasCode will be generated. So no different hashcode from Map after rehashing

Comment: @Mohit The goal is the keep number of hash bucket collisions to a minimum. Statistically speaking, the 75% load factor is a good average, where probability of collision increases dramatically when size gets above 75% of capacity. So, when that happens (a simple analysis that doesn't involve examining actual hash codes), the capacity is increased to keep the load below 75%. You seem to be suggesting a much more complex analysis to detect when the capacity should be increased, an analysis that is much slower (not good), and only needed if hash codes are badly distributed. Why would they do that?

Comment: First, thanks for your comment and knowledge sharing. I agreed with your point but my point is if we do rehashing on the basis of capacity and not size then it will be more good. As if good hash is there then capacity will decrease in proportional to increases in size and in case of bad hashcode ,  it wont. So we can avoid rehashing in case of bad HashCode

Comment: @Mohit But the analysis needed to *detect* bad hash codes is costly. Why should all the good hash codes pay the cost of trying to minimize memory consumption for a bad implementation of `hashCode()`? Let the bad hash code take the performance hit, and allow good implementation to run at full speed. Besides, the improvement for a bad implementation would likely be small anyway, so adding code complexity to `HashMap` implementation just for that is a bad idea.